# ¿Si tengo un cliente que quiere un pagina de venta de ropa, como puedo hacer para que el mismo pueda modificar productos?

Tags: html, css

Estoy termianndo un curso, y necesito saber que se puede hacer o si es posible, el entregar una IU y que el usuario modofique su propio **sitio web**.
Soy jr y quisiera saber donde sacarme esas dudas

Comment: Cuando tengas suficiente [reputación](/help/privileges), podrás acceder al [chat del sitio](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/30872), donde la temática es más abierta. Las preguntas basadas en opiniones terminan [cerradas](/help/closed-questions).

Comment: Depende desde que contexto lo estas viendo, porque si tu sitio tiene un sistema de seguridad en donde hay usuarios, roles, acceso y permisos podrias crearle un usuario para que este pueda realizar cambios en el portal de venta.

Comment: Si se puede... wordpress por ejemplo ya lo tiene todo resuelto..